# Would a Cloudshift targeting Zada, Hedron Grinder also target tokens?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Zada, Hedron Grinder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Zada%2C%20Hedron%20Grinder) copies instants and sorceries that target him only for all the rest of my creature that the intant or sorcery could target. If I cast [Cloudshift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cloudshift), targeting Zada, would it create copies that target the token creatures I control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if you cast Cloudshift targeting your Zada, Hedron Grinder, Zada will make a copy of Cloudshift targeting each other creature you control, including tokens. Cloudshift says

> Exile **target creature you control**, then return that card to the battlefield under your control.

So, any creature you control is a valid target.

Note that when the copies resolve, any creature tokens you control will be exiled and they will not return, because of rule [110.5g](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Permanent):

> A token that has left the battlefield can’t move to another zone or come back onto the battlefield. If such a token would change zones, it remains in its current zone instead. It ceases to exist the next time state-based actions are checked; see rule 704.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, a token creature counts as a creature.**

A creature token behaves the same as a creature card on the battlefield.

Since Zada, Hedron Grinder says "each other creature you control", it will include all creatures, whether represented by a token or by a card.

From the glossary in the comprehensive rules:

> A marker used to represent any permanent that isn’t represented by a card.

And rule 110.5e:

> A token is subject to anything that affects permanents in general or that affects the token’s card type or subtype.